# Can a function be measurable but not with respect to a finer topology?

Tags: measure-theory

Is it possible to have a function $f: X \mapsto Y $ such that $f$ is measurable with respect to a toplogy $\tau _A $ on $Y $ but not with respect to a finer topology $\tau _B $?

For instance if $f $ is measurable with respect to the standard topology in $Y $ and the Borel-sigma algebra generated by to open sets in $X $. Does this imply that $f $ is measurable with respect to the power set on $Y $ and again the same borel sigma-algebra on $X $?

Any examples?

---

I difine a function $ f $ from a measure space $X $ to a topological space $Y $ as measurable if for every open subset of $Y $, $f^{-1 } (U) $ is an element of the $\sigma $ algebra on $X $.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example: The identity function $ \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is not measurable if you take the discrete topology on the range and standard topology (and Borel-sigma algebra) on the domain.

Answer (score 1):

In general this cannot be true, of course, since *any* function $f:X\to Y$ is measurable if you take the trivial topology on $Y$.